# Data Table Ajax Call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to fetch data from database through Jquery DataTable and it gives error as:

> "DataTables warning: table id=tblBindData - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable."

```
function BindData() {

    $("#tblBindData").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "FirstTask.aspx/PopulateDatatable",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({});
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": function (msg) {
                    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                    fnCallback(json);
                    $("#tblBindData").show();
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    if (typeof console == "object") {
                        console.log(xhr.status + "," + xhr.responseText + "," + textStatus + "," + error);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: are you getting the right response from server?

Comment: In the current version of DataTables (1.10.4) you can simply add destroy:true to the configuration to make sure any table already present is removed before being re-initialised.  Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26968754/795683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code,

1. You have given `dataType` : `json` , then there is no need for using `jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d)`.
2. If you are using `"contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",` , then you should serialize your data before passing it to ajax. Better to remove `contentType` from yur ajax call.

Comment: ok thankyou it solved the case
but now it throws another error "Invalid JSON primitive:

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes do i have to make in the code so that i could fetch data

Comment: I am new to datatable and its not going on success function

Comment: please refer this link, you will get a better idea https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Sir please refer me to an asp.net example <br/> I am not a php developer