# Update jQuery dataTable from Firestore realtime querySnapshot

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using jQuery dataTable in my project to show some data from Firestore. Everything working properly, the problem is that when some data is updated in Firestore, following alert is appearing in browser:

```
DataTables warning: table id=student-dataTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. 
For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
```

I understand what the error is trying to say, but how do i solve the problem?

Following is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataSet = [];
    let db = firebase.firestore();

    let query = db.collectionGroup("members").where("class", "==", "9");

    let observer = query.onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot){
        console.log("Got data");
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                dataSet.push([doc.data().memberName, doc.data().phone ]);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("querySnapshot in empty");
        }
        $('#student-dataTable').DataTable({
            data: dataSet,
            destroy: true,
            columns: [
                { title: "Name" },
                { title: "Phone" },
            ]
        });
    });    
  });
```

And the HTML code:

```
<table id="student-dataTable">
```

So can anyone help me on how to rebuild my Table when Firestore data updates.
There is some info on [this](https://datatables.net/tn/3) link,it's suggesting to use **table.destroy();** but how do i use it to solve this?

I updated the code with `destroy: true` but when the table is reinitialized, all the data is pushed to `dataSet` variable each time, so every time data updates, each row is repeated in the table. How do the clean the `dataSet` variable each time.

Comment: store datatable into a variable something like this - 
`var table;
if(table) table.destroy();
table  = $('#student-dataTable').DataTable({ options...});`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot reinitialise DataTable - dynamic data for datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545792/cannot-reinitialise-datatable-dynamic-data-for-datatable)

Comment: Using in `Datatable({destroy: true})` is reinitialising the table, but all the rows are repeated.

Comment: repeated how?  and have you verified that the data you're handing over to the datatable doesn't have the "repeated" rows?

Comment: How do i reset the `dataSet` variable before the table is rebuild. Because it contains old data also, and new data is again pushed to `dataSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the old data before pushing to the array. Reset the array:

`dataSet = [] // Inside the onSnapshot function`